# Laravel - Export

Tags: php, laravel, export, relationship

I have created a website where users can create trips. Each trip has a trip itinerary with list of events.

I have added an export button here where the user can save their itinerary as an excel spreadsheet.
[image]

The export button downloads an excel sheet with the fields shown in image below. I want to change what is shown on the excel spreadsheet.

I have a one to many relationship between 'trip' table and 'events' table.

Once a user clicks on their trip itinerary they view their list of events in table below. I want these to be in the export download.

[image]

[image]

The excel sheet should only show only the one trip that a user clicks to export.

I want the excel sheet to display
Destination
Trip start date
Trip end date
Event(s) Name(s)
Event start date
Event end date
Event Time
Event Address

**Trip Table in Database**

**[image: Trip Table in database]**

**Events Table in Database**

[image]

**Trips.blade.php**

```
  <th>
        <a href="{{route('export')}}" class="btn btn-secondary">Export</a>
      </th>
```

**TripController.php**

```
public function export() {
    return Excel::download(new TripsExport, 'trips.xlsx');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMapping;

class InvoicesExport implements FromQuery, WithMapping
{    
    /**
    * @var Invoice $invoice
    */
    public function map($invoice): array
    {
        return [
            $invoice->invoice_number,
            $invoice->user->name,
            Date::dateTimeToExcel($invoice->created_at),
        ];
    }
}
```

Please read documentation about mapping data which you want to export. 
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/mapping.html